# WPF associate value with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, checkbox

I am new to WPF and am having issues with associating a value with an object.  I have a TreeView with CheckBoxes and I am wondering how I can associate an object to each checkbox.  I want to be able to select all the checked checkboxes (no problem) and get a list of objects that are associated with each checked box.

For example, let's say I have a class called Fruit that has properties DisplayName and Price

TreeView:

- Mango
- ✓  Apple
- Orange

I want to be able to return the Apple object so that I can get the Price and other properties associated to the Fruit.

Here is a code sample for me adding checkboxes to the TreeView

```
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();

CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
chkBox.IsChecked = false;
chkBox.Content = "Value";
chkBox.IsThreeState = false;
chkBox.Click += chkBox_Click;

treeViewItem.Header = chkBox;
```

Comment: Would you please show a code sample? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TreeViewItem inherits from FrameworkElement which provides the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) for this very purpose. You can set this property to an arbitrary object of your choosing. In this  case, you would set it to the appropriate fruit object.

Example:

```
chkBox.Tag = appleObj;
```

#### Another Option

As an option, have you considered binding the TreeView's ItemsSource property to a collection of your fruit objects? You would set the TreeView's [DisplayMemember property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) (which in inherits from ItemsControl) to the property on your fruit class that contains the name of the particular fruit. This would save you the work of hard-coding your check boxes.